# VBNet Reading csv file - separating column in a row - comma delimited

Tags: vb.net, csv

This has been bugging me for a week and i do not see any other way. We have only been taught record data structures which is basic, FileOpen, WriteLine and etc. but i read MSDN and StreamWriter/Reader looks much more promising. This is an assignment/coursework and its essential for practically all parts of the program.

All i want to do is read line by line separating fields by a comma and define it as a variable. It would also help to be able to read the line without the quotes "", because right now when i read a password out with LineInput it reads it entirely "pass".

```
Private Sub StudentLogin()
    Dim Filename As New StreamWriter("" & Register.StudentDirectory & "" & Username & ".txt")
    Dim str As String = "This"
    Dim lines() As String = str.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim columns() As String = line.Split(","c)
        Firstname = columns(0)
        Surname = columns(1)
        Password = columns(2)
        ClassID = columns(3)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("" & ClassID & " " & Password & "")
End Sub
```

Text file:

```
"cem","polat","pass","class"
```

I just want to read the file - then each line, row by row, defining each column field which is in **C:/Spellcheck/data/accounts/students/+filename+** and define a few variables.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

Comment: (REWRITTEN) More sample, simple codes showing how to use StreamReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx#fbid=2mTZ5B6sMS5 (under examples) and http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader-vbnet